# C# Interop with GetNamedPipeClientComputerName

Tags: c#, interop, named-pipes

I'm trying to use an interop call get the process ID and computer name of a named pipe client in C#:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(IntPtr Pipe, out uint ClientProcessId);

private static uint GetClientProcessID(NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer)
{
    uint processId;
    IntPtr pipeHandle = pipeServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
    if (GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(pipeHandle, out processId))
    {
        return processId;
    }
    return 0;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetNamedPipeClientComputerName(IntPtr Pipe, out string ClientComputerName, uint ClientComputerNameLength);

private static string GetClientComputerName(NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer)
{
    string computerName;
    uint buffer = 32768;
    IntPtr pipeHandle = pipeServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
    if (GetNamedPipeClientComputerName(pipeHandle, out computerName, buffer))
    {
        return computerName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` call is working, but `GetNamedPipeClientComputerName` is returning false.  What would be causing that one to fail?

Comment: Is it possible that the Entrypoint does not match your method name? I was only able to find [GetNamedPipeClientComputerNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getnamedpipeclientcomputernamea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetNamedPipeClientComputerName(IntPtr Pipe, StringBuilder ClientComputerName, uint ClientComputerNameLength);
```

Then, you need to call it like this:

```
var computerName = new StringBuilder(buffer);
...
if (GetNamedPipeClientComputerName(pipeHandle, computerName, buffer))
{
    return computerName.ToString();
}
else throw new Win32Exception();
```

Comment: Still returning false.  The exception thrown is `IOException: Pipe is broken.`, however without this call the subsequent code works fine.

Comment: OK, so it was still failing because it looks like that is expected when the client is local.  When I tested from a remote system, it works.